# Django error - refers to field 'n' that is missing from the form

Tags: python, django, fieldset

I'm getting to grips with Django, and practising by building a club membership site. In my admin.py for the app I created for members I'm getting the following error thrown:

> 'StudentAdmin.fieldsets[3][1]['fields']' refers to field 'n' that is missing from the form.

Here's the section of models.py it references (the _CHOICES tuples work fine):

```
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
dob = models.DateField(default='01/01/2000')
phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
email = models.EmailField()
address = models.TextField()
grade = models.CharField(max_length=7,
                         choices=GRADE_CHOICES,
                         default='10THGUP')
school = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                          choices=SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                          default='RED')
insurancedate = models.DateField(default='01/01/2001')
emergencycontact = models.CharField(max_length=40)
emergencycontactnumber = models.CharField(max_length=13)
notes = models.TextField()
```

and here's the admin.py that's causing the problem:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from members.models import Student

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

fieldsets = (
    ('Personal Details', {'fields': ('firstname', 'surname','dob','address','phone','email')
    }),
    ('Training', {'fields': ('grade', 'school', 'insurancedate')
    }),
    ('Emergency Contact', {'fields': ('emergencycontact', 'emergencycontactnumber',),
                           'classes': ('collapse')
    }),
    ('Other', {'fields': ('notes')
    }),
)

admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

Is it something stupid I'm missing? The default dates are in models.py as I used python-evolution to add the fields after the first syncdb, and it didn't want to create them with no values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably should make the line

```
('Other', {'fields': ('notes')
```

become

```
('Other', {'fields': ('notes',)
```

So it knows its a tuple and not a string